# Google Maps V2 Release Key Generating Issue

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am trying to `generate release key` for Google Maps V2 and for that i am following this [article](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/displaying-sha1-certificate-fingerprint.html), but i am getting:

```
keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, APP.keystore is not a legal command

java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, APP.keystore is not a legal command
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.parseArgs(KeyTool.java:402)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:193)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:188)
```

this is `how i am trying` to generate release key:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /home/system/APKs/Field APP.keystore -alias Field APP
```

Comment: You need to apply your `keystore` file path in `double quotation` `("")` .

Comment: I had to remove APP keyword from the project name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead with this:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "/home/system/APKs/Field APP.keystore" -alias Field APP
```

Comment: I had to remove the APP keyword from the project name, so finally i used this: keytool -list -v -keystore "/home/system/APKs/Field.keystore" -alias Field